# Typescript: How to reference property name in an string index signature definition in an interface

Tags: string, typescript, properties, reference, index-signature

#### Illustration

```
export interface IEventDef {
    ready: any,
}

export interface IIPCMessage {
    eventType: keyof IEventDef,
    data: IEventDef[this['eventType']]
}

interface IMessageHandlers {
    [eventName: keyof IEventDef]: (data: ) => void
}
```

#### Question

As per the illustration giving a string index signature for an interface!
As below:

```
interface IMessageHandlers {
    [eventName: keyof IEventDef]: (data: /*HOW_TO_REF_eventName*/) => void
}
```

How can we reference the `eventName` in my example? Or the index property name! Of the same line

In my exact code I wanted to do this:

```
interface IMessageHandlers {
    [eventName: keyof IEventDef]: (data: IEventDef[thisLineProp]) => void
}
```

Which would give a great affinity! any way?

To clear better I'll take this snippet below!

```
export interface IEventDef {
    ready: any,
} 

export interface IIPCMessage {
    eventType: keyof IEventDef,
    data: IEventDef[this['eventType']] // <<= here
}
```

In that example I was able to reference the same interface with `this` keyword! Which allow great type affinity! And it allowed nice typing precision!

What about referencing and getting the property name of the same line from the index signature?

### Update

I noticed that I just met the

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)`

Error!

And I changed the code to

```
type IMessageHandlers = {
    [eventName in keyof IEventDef]: (data: /*REF_THE_PROP_NAME?*/) => void
}
```

And I go with the question for this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want to use it? It's unclear from the invalid typings what the expected result is. If I understand the problem so far, your last example is very close if you replace `/*REF_THE_PROP_NAME?*/` with `eventName` (assuming you want `data` to be typed the same as the key name)

Comment: Yea that what was it! I want to use on the second part the same name as the property!
So From a usage point! When the object property is chosen! The mapped element will have automatically it's type inferred and correctly and with precision! And As you mentionned! i just had to use `eventName`! But at first i tried it, but in the interface! And with literal strings! and they are just not supported! And i didn't try with the `in` syntax. And that was my bad hhh! Any thoughts about when we need an interface!? Besides code generation! Thank you a lot sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there actually. `eventName` holds the type you want.

```
type IMessageHandlers = {
    [eventName in keyof IEventDef]: (data: eventName) => void
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWASQKIDcqQCJRzADeAUMBcDFAgCYCeAXMAmPQDSkC+wp540eMlRo0ABQDCAWSgBnWQgDmqMpWBQckACr0ADlGYBrKPQD2RTJogE4nNbQQQEzS7muEA2hAAWIWR4ByDTcdfQCAXXDgAHpo4AAeeIBeYG9YKG4+CD0RGXklKAAJVloAG1hZYBTVSg9gyAA5BABbVHBgYzMLbDcbcOYACgcnZnqIJtaASiqAPmAsUxBaTNIkUzBZCGBW-OVisDKK4Bc8hT2S8phK6vIqGgZj4AGxiahppLm1jdNygDpS0yKZ5WV6TFY7M5FC4VX7UOj0AYAIjhDERkwA3EA)

Comment: I was just there! i tried it ! However it was in the interface case! In the interface case we don't have it! And it make sense! I forget about the string only error! And unless they add support for `in` and the support for literal ! There is nothing that we can do! And in short this is possible through the `in` syntax! And we can use it in object literals! And we miss this on Interfaces!  There was consideration for it! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5683! It may spawn somewhere in the future! Thank you a lot Sir! And would appreciate any more thoughts!

Comment: For interfaces and the problem of literal support! We can always generate the interfaces! And we can have a plugin for it too! through the use of AST (ts-morph is a good choice).